# Getting all the users who are not in the particular group in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've searched and tried a lot, but unfortunately, I didn't solve my problem. So, I'm posting my question here, please look and suggest me some solution.

I have few tables to manage users like `users`, `profiles`, `groups`, and `group_user`. Now, I want to retrieve all user name which are not the member of a particular group.

**Efforts**

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->join('profiles', 'users.id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
->join('group_user AS gu', 'gu.user_id', '!=', 'users.id')
->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'gu.group_id')
->where('groups.label', '=', $grouplabel)
->lists(DB::raw("CONCAT_WS(' ',profiles.firstname, profiles.lastname) AS name"),'users.id as id');
```

I'm executing the query above to get list of users which are not the member of a particular group, but I'm not able to solve it 'til now.
If I change `!= to =` then I get the result of all users who are in the particular group.

Table record and structure in the image. [image: record in DB]

As, you can see I have 5 users, out of which 3 users having admin group and 2 are not. If I run the query for admin group, then there should be remaining 2 user or if I run query for test group then I should get 5 users.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to change the `join` part, all you need to change or add up in  your `where()` section

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->join('profiles', 'users.id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
->join('group_user AS gu', 'gu.user_id', '=', 'users.id') // mark it as '='
->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'gu.group_id')
->where('groups.label', '<>', $grouplabel) // change here, see below description
->lists(DB::raw("CONCAT_WS(' ',profiles.firstname, profiles.lastname) AS name"),'users.id as id');
```

this will ignore the particular group (eg: `profile`) and will return all other users except this group `(profile)`

**Edited**

I just removed the profile section from query, to verify the relationships, once you get the results then we will add up profile section, just run this query

```
select * from users as u
    inner join group_user as gu 
    on 
    gu.user_id = u.id 

    inner join groups as g
    on 
    g.id = gu.group_id where 
    groups.label <> 'Tester'
```

**Edited 2**

```
    $users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('profiles', 'users.id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
    ->join('group_user AS gu', 'gu.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'gu.group_id'); 

//if users exists in specific group
if($users->where('groups.label', '=', $grouplabel)->count() > 0 ){
   $result = $users->where('groups.label', '=', $grouplabel)
->lists(DB::raw("CONCAT_WS(' ',profiles.firstname, profiles.lastname) AS name"),'users.id as id');

} // return all users 
else{
      $result = $users->lists(DB::raw("CONCAT_WS(' ',profiles.firstname, profiles.lastname) AS name"),'users.id as id');
}
```

Comment: I am not getting anything.

Comment: what you not getting ? query results or my answer ?

Comment: results, empty [] array i am getting. If i copied the query and paste into phpmyadmin sql then also i am getting empty resultset.

Comment: can you show me the plain query so I can look into query?

Comment: "select CONCAT_WS(' ',profiles.firstname, profiles.lastname) AS name, `users`.`id` as `id` from `users` inner join `profiles` on `users`.`id` = `profiles`.`user_id` inner join `group_user` as `gu` on `gu`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` inner join `groups` on `groups`.`id` = `gu`.`group_id` where `groups`.`label` <> ?"

Comment: I have updated my question with record as image, please look and suggest me the solution.

Comment: check my update answer, and run the following query, check you what you getting

Comment: No, Its not giving me the correct output. i change tester with admin, i not get all user name.

Comment: why you change the tester, run my query as it as, and show me the results. after that we will change query

Comment: as you want result for `Admin`  so now just change the `where` section by this `where groups.label = 'Tester' you will get records for tester users. make sure you should have users in tester group, otherwise result will be empty

Comment: If i am not having any user in tester group then the query should return all users and if having then should return remaining users who are not in this group.

Comment: There should be a use of subquery like this select CONCAT_WS(' ',profiles.firstname, profiles.lastname) AS name, `users`.`id` as `id` from `users` inner join `profiles` on `users`.`id` = `profiles`.`user_id`  where users.id not in (select gu.user_id from `group_user` as `gu` inner join `groups` on `groups`.`id` = `gu`.`group_id` where `groups`.`label` ='Tester'). But i don't know how to use sub queries in laravel.

Comment: its better to avoid the use of sub queries, because it will slow down the performance. better to use to this way, I mentioned in answer

Comment: I know, but i am not having any option.

Comment: if you know that how to write `sub query` then you can write in laravel `whereRaw()` clause

Comment: Ok. Thanks, i'll try this.